# JS Syntax Error after deploying to CloudFlare

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite, svelte, cloudflare

I have a static website built using Svelte (4.2.10) + Vite (5.1.1) + TypeScript (5.2.2).

When I run the developmental frontend by running `vite` locally, it runs fine and renders without any problem. When I build the website using `vite build` and use `miniserve` to serve the dist static directory, it also renders completely fine.

However, when I deploy the website on Cloudflare and open the deployed website, the browser complains about a SyntaxError and does not render.

I have created a minimal reproducible example at https://gitlab.com/hykilpikonna/vite-reproducible-bug. The only dependency required to reproduce this behaviour seems to be `core-js`. The bugged version can be accessed at https://test0213.hydev.org/ - this page should show "1,2,3,4,5" but instead shows a SyntaxError in the console.

Some properties of this bug:

- It cannot be reproduced when I deploy to Cloudflare pages without a domain (i.e. https://vite-reproducible-bug.pages.dev/ works as intended)
- It cannot be reproduced when deployed locally using Nginx.
- It does not immediately show up. It only appears after refreshing the page when the developer console is open. However, after the bug shows up, refreshing the page doesn't fix it.
- I have tried different browsers and clean profiles, which all showed this behaviour, so it couldn't be caused by my browser extensions.

Steps to replicate this bug from scratch:

1. Create a vite svelte project using `npm create vite@latest`
2. Install `core-js`, import and use it in your code
3. Deploy it to CloudFlare pages (I used GitHub and GitLab integrations)
4. Set a CloudFlare domain URL for the CloudFlare pages.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking into the network tab if something didn't load as expected?

Comment: @derpirscher there are no network errors. The SyntaxError is the only error that happened when loading the page.

Comment: `1.toString` is invalid syntax, so it’s probably a minifier bug. Your minimal reproducible example doesn’t seem to be a public repo, by the way.

Comment: @Ry- I did not use any extra minifier when building my page. The result of `vite build` is minified and it does not have the bug.

Comment: A Cloudflare minifier bug specifically then, if you’re running that. The original source has `1 .toString` with a space, an easy case to overlook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloudflare auto-minification is turning `1 .toString` into `1.toString`, breaking the syntax. This has been [a known bug since at least 2022](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/auto-minify-breaks-javascript-syntax/417399). Given that you’re already minifying your assets as is best practice, you should turn off the redundant layer; it’ll only slow down and break things.

The setting can be found in your Cloudflare dashboard at Websites > [your website] > Speed > Optimization > Content Optimization > Auto Minify > JavaScript.